# Is there a way to get an element of another element in python/selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have to extract the name input in a field in a python script I'm writing (using selenium).  Here is the html.

`<div id="CF00NC000000576hm_ileinner"><a onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup005C0000003xG8C00NC000000576hm', '/005C0000003xG8C/m?retURL=%2F00QC000001DMZB8&amp;isAjaxRequest=1&amp;nocache=1370473054922').show();" onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup005C0000003xG8C00NC000000576hm').hide();" onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup005C0000003xG8C00NC000000576hm', '/005C0000003xG8C/m?retURL=%2F00QC000001DMZB8&amp;isAjaxRequest=1&amp;nocache=1370473054922').show();" onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('lookup005C0000003xG8C00NC000000576hm').hide();" id="lookup005C0000003xG8C00NC000000576hm" href="/005C0000003xG8C">James Brown</a></div>`

The xpath is `//*[@id="CF00NC000000576hm_ileinner"]`.

My best guess as to how to go about this is using:

```
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CF00NC000000576hm_ileinner"]')
elem2 = elem1.get_attribute("innerHTML")
elem3 = elem2.get_attribute("innerHTML")
print elem3
```

I want the script to output "James Brown" in this case.

I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'`

Answer (score 1):

Have you try (if you need only text "James Brown")

```
 print elem1.text
```

You get error because `elem2` or `elem3` is string - not selenium object - and have no `get_attribute()` function. Try:

```
 elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CF00NC000000576hm_ileinner"]')

 print elem1

 elem2 = elem1.get_attribute("innerHTML")

 print elem2

 elem3 = elem2.get_attribute("innerHTML")

 print elem3
```